# Test for spatial autocorrelation in panel data

Tags: r, spatial, panel-data

I'm trying to test for spatial autocorrelations in my linear models residuals. I have a panel data with with 98 ID over 2 years.

Here's the data:

```
df <- structure(list(yr = structure(c(2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 
2014, 2015, 2014, 2015), format.stata = "%8.0g"), ID = structure(c("København", 
"København", "Frederiksberg", "Frederiksberg", "Ballerup", "Ballerup", 
"Brøndby", "Brøndby", "Dragør", "Dragør", "Gentofte", "Gentofte", 
"Gladsaxe", "Gladsaxe", "Glostrup", "Glostrup", "Herlev", "Herlev", 
"Albertslund", "Albertslund", "Hvidovre", "Hvidovre", "Høje-Taastrup", 
"Høje-Taastrup", "Lyngby-Taarbæk", "Lyngby-Taarbæk", "Rødovre", 
"Rødovre", "Ishøj", "Ishøj", "Tårnby", "Tårnby", "Vallensbæk", 
"Vallensbæk", "Furesø", "Furesø", "Allerød", "Allerød", 
"Fredensborg", "Fredensborg", "Helsingør", "Helsingør", "Hillerød", 
"Hillerød", "Hørsholm", "Hørsholm", "Rudersdal", "Rudersdal", 
"Egedal", "Egedal", "Frederikssund", "Frederikssund", "Greve", 
"Greve", "Køge", "Køge", "Halsnæs", "Halsnæs", "Roskilde", 
"Roskilde", "Solrød", "Solrød", "Gribskov", "Gribskov", "Odsherred", 
"Odsherred", "Holbæk", "Holbæk", "Faxe", "Faxe", "Kalundborg", 
"Kalundborg", "Ringsted", "Ringsted", "Slagelse", "Slagelse", 
"Stevns", "Stevns", "Sorø", "Sorø", "Lejre", "Lejre", "Lolland", 
"Lolland", "Næstved", "Næstved", "Guldborgsund", "Guldborgsund", 
"Vordingborg", "Vordingborg", "Bornholm", "Bornholm", "Middelfart", 
"Middelfart", "Assens", "Assens", "Faaborg-Midtfyn", "Faaborg-Midtfyn", 
"Kerteminde", "Kerteminde", "Nyborg", "Nyborg", "Odense", "Odense", 
"Svendborg", "Svendborg", "Nordfyns", "Nordfyns", "Langeland", 
"Langeland", "Ærø", "Ærø", "Haderslev", "Haderslev", "Billund", 
"Billund", "Sønderborg", "Sønderborg", "Tønder", "Tønder", 
"Esbjerg", "Esbjerg", "Fanø", "Fanø", "Varde", "Varde", "Vejen", 
"Vejen", "Aabenraa", "Aabenraa", "Fredericia", "Fredericia", 
"Horsens", "Horsens", "Kolding", "Kolding", "Vejle", "Vejle", 
"Herning", "Herning", "Holstebro", "Holstebro", "Lemvig", "Lemvig", 
"Struer", "Struer", "Syddjurs", "Syddjurs", "Norddjurs", "Norddjurs", 
"Favrskov", "Favrskov", "Odder", "Odder", "Randers", "Randers", 
"Silkeborg", "Silkeborg", "Samsø", "Samsø", "Skanderborg", 
"Skanderborg", "Aarhus", "Aarhus", "Ikast-Brande", "Ikast-Brande", 
"Ringkøbing-Skjern", "Ringkøbing-Skjern", "Hedensted", "Hedensted", 
"Morsø", "Morsø", "Skive", "Skive", "Thisted", "Thisted", "Viborg", 
"Viborg", "Brønderslev", "Brønderslev", "Frederikshavn", "Frederikshavn", 
"Vesthimmerlands", "Vesthimmerlands", "Læsø", "Læsø", "Rebild", 
"Rebild", "Mariagerfjord", "Mariagerfjord", "Jammerbugt", "Jammerbugt", 
"Aalborg", "Aalborg", "Hjørring", "Hjørring"), format.stata = "%18s"), 
    y = structure(c(16.1403503417969, 13.4935302734375, 21.7765045166016, 
    25.6559772491455, 22.761194229126, 23.6421718597412, 19.8847255706787, 
    19.4690265655518, 23.6842098236084, 15.740740776062, 12.6903553009033, 
    14.9321269989014, 21.9178085327148, 17.1232872009277, 18.3946495056152, 
    14.8594379425049, 13.4969329833984, 11.1111106872559, 28.7790699005127, 
    22.9461765289307, 20.5211734771729, 19.1919193267822, 19.6969699859619, 
    18.3266925811768, 14.0845069885254, 15.1785717010498, 29.6000003814697, 
    18.4549350738525, 16.549295425415, 15.4929580688477, 12.6666669845581, 
    12, 16.9491519927979, 16.5, 10.7142858505249, 9.65517234802246, 
    14.8325357437134, 8.42105293273926, 20.085470199585, 10.638298034668, 
    20, 17.1511631011963, 20.1511325836182, 18.8953495025635, 
    13.1355934143066, 11.640212059021, 24.4360904693604, 23.2824420928955, 
    20.220588684082, 14.8471612930298, 11.7283954620361, 13.8392858505249, 
    19.4029846191406, NA, 9.85915470123291, 8.69565200805664, 
    15.4639177322388, 19.1666660308838, 14.6892652511597, 15.8854169845581, 
    14.2276420593262, 9.49720668792725, 21.4765110015869, 14.0845069885254, 
    13.6690645217896, 10.3092784881592, 12.2448978424072, 16.1403503417969, 
    14.4859809875488, 13.9830513000488, NA, NA, 13.0081300735474, 
    20.4633197784424, 13.8047142028809, 16.5384616851807, 23.046875, 
    15.319149017334, 25.9414234161377, 20.6451606750488, 14.9484539031982, 
    17.6470584869385, NA, NA, 22.3776226043701, 15.5913982391357, 
    13.4920635223389, 15.5172414779663, 12.1518983840942, 14.5161294937134, 
    20.6185569763184, 19.3181819915771, 22.1476516723633, 21.7105255126953, 
    12.6394052505493, 7.43801641464233, 17.153284072876, 13.1086139678955, 
    NA, NA, 11.6504850387573, 9.21052646636963, 10.625, 14.7540979385376, 
    8.78048801422119, 6.77083349227905, 18.4331798553467, 18.7192115783691, 
    13.5231313705444, 14.1592922210693, 15.7360410690308, 11.764705657959, 
    20.071683883667, 17.8694152832031, 19.7604789733887, 13.9072847366333, 
    15.5172414779663, 20.948616027832, 20.6896553039551, 16.8421058654785, 
    17.1296291351318, 19.2660541534424, 12.037036895752, 9.84848499298096, 
    13.4259262084961, 10.7981224060059, 28.7037029266357, NA, 
    18.028169631958, 12.021858215332, 11.682243347168, 9.34065914154053, 
    10.7142858505249, 10.7806692123413, 14.0298509597778, 12.4579124450684, 
    NA, NA, 15.2238807678223, 14.6341466903687, 13.5245904922485, 
    12.707181930542, 15.9362554550171, 12.5, 24.6987953186035, 
    17.1875, 14.070351600647, 13.1914892196655, 27.5, 21.2765960693359, 
    21.0762329101562, 16.4835166931152, 14.2180099487305, 13.6094675064087, 
    25.3086414337158, 26.6129035949707, 14.4981412887573, 12.1951217651367, 
    15.6378602981567, 16.5094337463379, 17.7865619659424, 17.6991157531738, 
    21.4285717010498, 20.3791465759277, 18.7265911102295, 11.2727270126343, 
    16.5938873291016, 18.2389945983887, 12.5654449462891, 12.3456792831421, 
    16.4179096221924, 10.7692308425903, 16.8141593933105, 17.4273853302002, 
    NA, NA, 16.352201461792, 17.7631587982178, 17.0040493011475, 
    10.8597288131714, 11.1498260498047, 10.6918239593506, 15.8995819091797, 
    18.5792350769043, 20, 8.25688076019287, 12.9496402740479, 
    17.6954727172852, 12.037036895752, 12.8712873458862, 17.1597633361816, 
    16.6666660308838, 5.64516115188599, 11.4624509811401, NA, 
    NA), format.stata = "%9.0g"), x = structure(c(40, 40, 40, 
    40, 36, 36, 10.5263156890869, 10.5263156890869, 20, 20, 57.8947372436523, 
    57.8947372436523, 48, 48, 36.8421058654785, 36.8421058654785, 
    31.5789470672607, 31.5789470672607, 23.8095245361328, 23.8095245361328, 
    33.3333320617676, 33.3333320617676, 23.8095245361328, 23.8095245361328, 
    42.8571434020996, 42.8571434020996, 21.0526313781738, 21.0526313781738, 
    26.3157901763916, 26.3157901763916, 21.0526313781738, 21.0526313781738, 
    33.3333320617676, 33.3333320617676, 33.3333320617676, 33.3333320617676, 
    33.3333320617676, 33.3333320617676, 29.6296291351318, 29.6296291351318, 
    40, 40, 51.8518524169922, 51.8518524169922, 31.5789470672607, 
    31.5789470672607, 43.4782600402832, 43.4782600402832, 28.5714282989502, 
    28.5714282989502, 30.4347820281982, 30.4347820281982, 28.5714282989502, 
    28.5714282989502, 37.037036895752, 37.037036895752, 38.0952377319336, 
    38.0952377319336, 25.8064517974854, 25.8064517974854, 15.7894735336304, 
    15.7894735336304, 39.1304359436035, 39.1304359436035, 28, 
    28, 22.5806446075439, 22.5806446075439, 28, 28, 37.037036895752, 
    37.037036895752, 28.5714282989502, 28.5714282989502, 19.3548393249512, 
    19.3548393249512, 26.3157901763916, 26.3157901763916, 36, 
    36, 28, 28, 32.2580642700195, 32.2580642700195, 38.7096786499023, 
    38.7096786499023, 31.0344829559326, 31.0344829559326, 37.9310340881348, 
    37.9310340881348, 40.7407417297363, 40.7407417297363, 16, 
    16, 34.4827575683594, 34.4827575683594, 24, 24, 40, 40, 24, 
    24, 31.0344829559326, 31.0344829559326, 31.0344829559326, 
    31.0344829559326, 28, 28, 33.3333320617676, 33.3333320617676, 
    20, 20, 16.1290321350098, 16.1290321350098, 16, 16, 12.9032258987427, 
    12.9032258987427, 19.3548393249512, 19.3548393249512, 19.3548393249512, 
    19.3548393249512, 18.1818180084229, 18.1818180084229, 24, 
    24, 25.9259262084961, 25.9259262084961, 22.5806446075439, 
    22.5806446075439, 33.3333320617676, 33.3333320617676, 29.6296291351318, 
    29.6296291351318, 36, 36, 25.8064517974854, 25.8064517974854, 
    32.2580642700195, 32.2580642700195, 25.9259262084961, 25.9259262084961, 
    23.8095245361328, 23.8095245361328, 33.3333320617676, 33.3333320617676, 
    25.9259262084961, 25.9259262084961, 22.2222213745117, 22.2222213745117, 
    36, 36, 31.5789470672607, 31.5789470672607, 29.0322589874268, 
    29.0322589874268, 25.8064517974854, 25.8064517974854, 36.3636360168457, 
    36.3636360168457, 24.1379318237305, 24.1379318237305, 32.2580642700195, 
    32.2580642700195, 34.7826080322266, 34.7826080322266, 27.5862064361572, 
    27.5862064361572, 18.518518447876, 18.518518447876, 23.8095245361328, 
    23.8095245361328, 37.037036895752, 37.037036895752, 14.8148145675659, 
    14.8148145675659, 35.4838714599609, 35.4838714599609, 22.2222213745117, 
    22.2222213745117, 32.2580642700195, 32.2580642700195, 44.4444427490234, 
    44.4444427490234, 22.2222213745117, 22.2222213745117, 16, 
    16, 27.5862064361572, 27.5862064361572, 29.6296291351318, 
    29.6296291351318, 38.7096786499023, 38.7096786499023, 29.0322589874268, 
    29.0322589874268), format.stata = "%9.0g"), polygon.nr = c(24L, 
    24L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
    14L, 14L, 20L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 22L, NA, NA, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
    26L, 23L, 23L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 
    8L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 17L, 17L, 27L, 27L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 
    10L, 61L, 61L, 64L, 64L, 18L, 18L, 71L, 71L, 73L, 73L, 15L, 
    15L, 69L, 69L, 63L, 63L, 60L, 60L, 65L, 65L, 70L, 70L, 72L, 
    72L, 75L, 75L, 74L, 74L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 62L, 
    62L, 76L, 76L, 4L, 4L, 89L, 89L, 79L, 79L, 82L, 82L, 86L, 
    86L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 94L, 94L, 90L, 90L, 88L, 88L, 77L, 
    77L, 85L, 85L, 80L, 80L, 93L, 93L, 95L, 95L, 81L, 81L, 83L, 
    83L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 78L, 78L, 84L, 84L, 35L, 35L, 87L, 
    87L, 98L, 98L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 37L, 37L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 
    47L, 38L, 38L, 31L, 31L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 43L, 43L, 42L, 
    42L, 44L, 44L, 30L, 30L, 36L, 36L, 41L, 41L, 32L, 32L, 56L, 
    56L, 45L, 45L, 58L, 58L, 48L, 48L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 59L, 
    59L, 54L, 54L, 57L, 57L, 55L, 55L, 53L, 53L, 49L, 49L, 52L, 
    52L)), row.names = c(NA, -196L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

The units are connected to each other the following neighborlist:

```
nb <- structure(list(c(3L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 16L, 29L), c(7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 
17L, 21L, 27L), c(1L, 7L, 11L, 14L, 20L), 0L, c(1L, 14L, 22L, 
26L, 29L), 28L, c(1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 71L), c(2L, 15L, 
17L, 19L, 21L), 24L, c(2L, 7L, 18L, 21L, 66L, 71L), c(2L, 3L, 
7L, 13L, 20L, 25L, 27L), c(13L, 24L, 25L), c(11L, 12L, 20L, 24L, 
25L), c(1L, 3L, 5L, 20L, 26L), c(8L, 18L, 19L, 21L), c(1L, 7L, 
23L, 29L, 61L, 71L), c(2L, 8L, 27L), c(10L, 15L, 21L), c(8L, 
15L), c(3L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 24L, 26L), c(2L, 8L, 10L, 15L, 18L
), c(5L, 24L, 26L, 28L), c(16L, 29L, 61L), c(9L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 
22L, 26L, 28L), c(11L, 12L, 13L, 27L), c(5L, 14L, 20L, 22L, 24L
), c(2L, 11L, 17L, 25L), c(6L, 22L, 24L), c(1L, 5L, 16L, 23L), 
    c(31L, 39L, 44L, 47L), c(30L, 40L, 43L, 44L, 47L, 48L), c(35L, 
    36L, 98L), c(34L, 36L, 41L, 48L, 80L), c(33L, 37L, 41L, 45L, 
    46L, 48L), c(32L, 36L, 39L, 43L, 44L), c(32L, 33L, 35L, 43L, 
    48L, 80L, 98L), c(34L, 46L), c(40L, 47L), c(30L, 35L, 44L
    ), c(31L, 38L, 47L, 48L, 55L), c(33L, 34L, 80L, 96L), 0L, 
    c(31L, 35L, 36L, 44L, 48L), c(30L, 31L, 35L, 39L, 43L), c(34L, 
    48L), c(34L, 37L, 58L), c(30L, 31L, 38L, 40L), c(31L, 33L, 
    34L, 36L, 40L, 43L, 45L, 55L, 59L), c(50L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 
    59L), c(49L, 51L, 52L, 53L), c(50L, 52L), c(50L, 51L, 53L
    ), c(49L, 50L, 52L, 58L, 59L), 0L, c(40L, 48L, 49L, 57L, 
    59L), 0L, c(49L, 55L, 59L), c(46L, 53L), c(48L, 49L, 53L, 
    55L, 57L), c(64L, 68L, 70L, 75L), c(16L, 23L, 71L, 73L), 
    67L, c(65L, 66L, 69L, 70L, 74L), c(60L, 66L, 70L, 71L, 73L, 
    75L), c(63L, 69L, 72L, 74L), c(10L, 63L, 64L, 70L, 71L), 
    62L, c(60L, 70L, 72L, 74L, 76L), c(63L, 65L), c(60L, 63L, 
    64L, 66L, 68L, 74L), c(7L, 10L, 16L, 61L, 64L, 66L, 73L), 
    c(65L, 68L, 74L), c(61L, 64L, 71L), c(63L, 65L, 68L, 70L, 
    72L), c(60L, 64L), 68L, 0L, c(85L, 93L, 95L), c(82L, 89L, 
    90L, 92L), c(33L, 36L, 41L, 96L, 97L, 98L), c(85L, 95L, 96L, 
    97L), c(79L, 86L, 91L, 92L, 94L), 0L, c(87L, 98L), c(78L, 
    81L, 87L, 95L, 97L), c(82L, 91L, 92L), c(84L, 85L, 97L, 98L
    ), 0L, c(79L, 90L), c(79L, 89L, 92L), c(82L, 86L, 94L), c(79L, 
    82L, 86L, 90L), 78L, c(82L, 91L), c(78L, 81L, 85L), c(41L, 
    80L, 81L, 97L), c(80L, 81L, 85L, 87L, 96L, 98L), c(32L, 36L, 
    80L, 84L, 87L, 97L)), class = "nb", region.id = c("0", "1", 
"2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", 
"37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", 
"48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", 
"59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", 
"70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", 
"81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", 
"92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98"), call = poly2nb(pl = kommuner, 
    queen = TRUE), type = "queen", sym = TRUE)
```

I then estimate the following model:

```
library(plm)
library(tidyverse)
library(spdep)

    m1 <- lm(y ~ x,
         data = df)
```

And test for spatial autocorrelation like this:

```
w1 <- nb2listw(nb, style ="W", zero.policy = TRUE)
r1 <- resid(m1)
moran.test(r1, w1)
```

This returns the error

> "Error in moran.test(r1, w1) : objects of different length"

I think the reason is the panel structure of my dataset. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check `dim(df): length(m1$fitted.values)` you have missings in the data that are deleted after `lm`.

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to use the Moran test for cross sectional data in a panel estimation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend your matrix to 2 time periods by Kronecker product and then apply the Moran test. You should organize your data following the time order first.